# Trimming chr(49824) in the middle of a field in oracle

Tags: oracle

Unable to trim the non breakable space in the middle of a filed in oracle
'766195491                             572'

Tried the below method it works only when non breakable space is present on the sides.

```
select length(trim(replace('766195491                             572',chr(49824),''))) from dual;
```

Comment: "Trim" by definition means "delete from the ENDS of the string" so "trimming in the middle" is nonsense. Then: do you need to remove the non-breakable space completely, or do you need to REPLACE it with a BREAKABLE space (standard space, `chr(32)`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `CHR(32)`  instead of `CHR(49824)`

```
select length(replace('766195491                             572',chr(32),'')) from dual;
```

If it does not work, use something like this.

```
select length(regexp_replace('766195491                             572','[^-a-zA-Z0-9]','') ) from dual;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30600/12)

Answer (score 0):

> it works only when non breakable space is present on the sides

That’s what [the `trim()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRIM.html) is supposed to do:

> `TRIM` enables you to trim leading or trailing characters (or both) from a character string

“leading or trailing” means “at the sides”. It is not supposed to have any effect on appearances of the characters anywhere else in the source string.

You need to use the [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REPLACE.html) or [`translate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html) functions instead; or for more complicated scenarios, regular expression functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the input value is in a column named `input_str`, then:

```
translate(input_str, chr(49824), chr(32))
```

will replace every non-breakable space in the input string with a regular (breakable) space.

If you simply want to remove all non-breakable spaces and don't want to replace them with anything, then

```
replace(input_str, chr(49824))
```

(if you omit the third argument, the result is simply removing all occurrences of the second argument).

Perhaps the requirement is more complicated though; find all occurrences of one **or more** *consecutive* non-breaking spaces and replace each such occurrence with exactly one standard space. That is more easily achieved with a regular expression function:

```
regexp_replace(input_str, chr(49824) || '+', chr(32))
```